# How to create a model in django that is not linked to any table in database mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, model

I have a table in firestore, and I try to create model from firestore database using firebase-orm and use admin.register(modelFireStore) in Admin django but it seems Django doesn't support register modelFirstore in admin.
I need to create a model without linking to any table in mysql and I can override django's CRUD to CRUD table in firestore. Is this possible

error admin.register with modelFirestore created by Firebase-orm: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8Z8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqUYo.png)

The problem is as follows,My project Django is curently connect database mysl, specifically I have a config table on firestore and I need it to appear in the admin page to CRUD on firestore.
In django have to use admin.register(model) to be able to CRUD in firestore, And am struggling how to create modelFIrestore and admin.register(modelFirestore). I tried with firebaseOrm but admin.register doesn't recognize modelFirestore and gives meta error as below image.

there is a solution is to create a table like the one in firestore and declare the model and use admin.register(modelSQL), but the table in mysql seems redundant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is as follows, specifically I have a config table on firestore and I need it to appear in the admin page to CRUD on firestore.
In django have to use admin.register(model) to be able to CRUD in firestore, And am struggling how to create modelFIrestore and admin.register(modelFirestore). I tried with firebaseOrm but admin.register doesn't recognize modelFirestore and gives meta error

Comment: ok i figured out how to override django templdate with changelist_view so maybe no need to map model from firestore anymore, thanks @jahantaila